# Privoxy, proxy some domain, and exclude some sub-domain

Tags: proxy, config

I use privoxy action file for proxy some domain, it works well

```
{{alias}}
proxy = +forward-override{forward-socks5 localhost:55501 .}

{proxy}
.demo1.com
.demo2.com
```

now I want exclude some sub-domain, for example:

```
noproxy.demo1.com
```

What should I write in the action file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put this code behind:

```
{-forward-override}
noproxy.demo1.com
```

`-` to disable.

And [From the manual](http://config.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html):

> For multi-valued actions, the actions are applied in the order they are specified.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue. The answer above is almost correct.

Documentation on https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#FORWARD-OVERRIDE says

```
"forward ." to use a direct connection without any additional proxies.
```

So, correcting the previous answer:

```
{+forward-override{forward .}}
yourdomain.com
```

Will do bypass the proxies for yourdomain.com